# utilizar el segundo select con un input - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

tengo un inconveniente puntual , envio solo el código que tengo problemas, tengo dos select y un input, el input esta cargando el valor que seleccione en el primer select + 1 ahora lo que necesito es que no me coja el valor del primer select si no del segundo select sin desconfigurar el codigo que tiene este segundo select.

código completo

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-rain-m87ep?file=/src/App.js:11268-12592

```js
 const setSelect = (value) => {
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray ) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
    if (isArray ) {
        setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre * 1 + 1 }) ;
      
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
   
  }
  
  
  const handleInput_division = (event) => {
  
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });

 setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
 
};


  return (
  
   <select name='' class='form-control'   onChange={handleInput_division}>
   <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
                                   
   </select>
   
    <select  onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name='' >
            <option value='9'>5</option>
           <option value='10'>6</option>  
             
          </select>
          
  //input
  {rows.map((e, index) => (
        <Row
          nombre={e.nombre}
          index={index}
          onChange={(index, value) => handleOnChange(index, value)}
          key={index}
        />
)
```

Comment: Por favor comparte el código completo, copie y pege tu código y obtengo errores de que faltan llarves y corchetes.

Comment: ya agregue el código completo...

Comment: El codigo completo funciona de la siguiente forma: primero aparece un input que pide un valor y le doy al boton del lado, luego carga un select que se llama "2-grupos" y selecciono un valor luego le doy al boton del lado,  luego aparece un input con un valor fijo y le damos al boton del lado asi hasta que aparece el 4 y ultimo select y le demos al boton del lado luego abajo nos carga un select con la cantidad de valores que colocamos en el input 3, y seleccionamos un valor y de forma automatica nos carga un boton y le damos clic y nos aparece un un input el cual carga el valor del select 2 ...

Comment: "grupos" y le suma + 1. Ahora lo que necesito es que es que este input ya no me cargue el valor del select 2 "grupos " si no que cargue el valor del select que aparece abajo despues de darle en el boton del lado del cuarto campo "select ".

Comment: alguien me puede colaborar?